# VideoJS - Flash Player crash when moving in the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, video.js, flash-video

I have a Video.js flash player (the requirement is that it be flash, so I am using it in flash mode as the tech). It sits as a main 'jumbotron' type video on the top of the page. When the user scrolls down, it needs to detach and appendTo the dom tree in the sidebar. The problem is, when it does, the video crashes (at least I think it is a crash), resets to 0.00 time, and is just black. It cannot be restarted without reloading the page.

Has anyone had any success in moving a flash video across the DOM without a crash with video.js? If not video.js, do you recommend a player that could do this? I have succeeded in having it work with HTML5 video in video.js, but flash is the requirement.

Thank you

Comment: detach/appendTo creates a new element and destroys the old one – so you can’t expect the video play position to stay where it was. I’d try to place it inside the side bar to begin with, and use absolute positioning to get it to show as a “jumbotron” from there.

Comment: Will try this and report back. Seems like a good thought to try.

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't or at least I cannot get it to work well in a 'right sticky rail' scenario. Having said that, I went back and are testing a different idea, namely, setting it to a right static rail and having overlay there. However, I also think that it would be the perfect opportunity to have it be the reverse (start in the jumbotron and relative position right of it).

Comment: Ok, so in the situation above, I got it to work by doing what you said, but opposite ways. It worked out surprisingly well.

Comment: OK, I’ve added this as a (short) answer. Feel free to post a self-answer as well (if you can include an example that shows how what you’ve done now works.)

Comment: Yea, ill add a self answer on tuesday (not in the office till then). I marked as answered and thanks for the assist @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detach/appendTo creates a new element and destroys the old one – so you can’t expect the video play position to stay where it was.

I’d try to place it inside the side bar to begin with, and use absolute positioning to get it to show as a “jumbotron” from there. (Or, as you said, the other way around, if that works better in your actual scenario.)